# Facebook review slideshow is not aligned properly on mobile - HTML CODE

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, facebook, shopify

I am having trouble aligning the HTML slideshow on mobile (I am using the embed review code from facebook).

For some reason, only the first review is shown aligned on mobile, but when the slideshow switches to the next slide the review is not shown aligned properly.

This URL will show you the result on the site:
https://oriavivi.com/pages/facebook-review

I have tried several codes with javascript and this last one from W3 school to pull it off but with no luck so far:

```html
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script async="" defer="defer" crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/he_IL/sdk.js#xfbml=1&amp;version=v8.0" nonce=""></script>
<script src="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.js"></script>
<div align="center">
<div class="nature">
<div class="fb-post" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/tamila.meerzon/posts/3506844522677465" data-show-text="true" data-width="20">
<blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/tamila.meerzon/posts/3506844522677465" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
<p>שלום לכולם.לפני כמה ימים מצאתי את האתר והזמנתי פעם הראשונה. עשיתי החלטה מצויינת. גם הכרתי מעצבת נחמדה ומקצועית וגם אישה...</p>
פורסם על ידי ‏‎<a href="https://www.facebook.com/tamila.meerzon">Tamila Meerzon</a>‎‏ ב- <a href="https://www.facebook.com/tamila.meerzon/posts/3506844522677465">יום רביעי, 20 במאי 2020</a></blockquote>
</div>
</div>
<div class="nature">
<div class="fb-post" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/meytal.grinberg/posts/10158027741254670" data-show-text="true" data-width="20">
<blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/meytal.grinberg/posts/10158027741254670" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
<p>אמאלה מושלם!!!!! צמיד נעים,איכותי ומהמם. מקבלת עליו מלא מחמאות... שירות אישי ומשלוח סופר מהיר ושירותי! ממליצה בחום❤❤❤ צמיד ראשון ובטוח לא אחרון</p>
פורסם על ידי ‏‎<a href="#" role="button">Meytal Grinberg</a>‎‏ ב- <a href="https://www.facebook.com/meytal.grinberg/posts/10158027741254670">יום שישי, 7 בפברואר 2020</a></blockquote>
</div>
</div>
<div class="nature">
<div class="fb-post" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/galit.bitton.7/posts/10222133077450392" data-show-text="true" data-width="20">
<blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/galit.bitton.7/posts/10222133077450392" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
<p>השרות האדיב, העיצוב המשגע, מעבר לזה שרכשתי צמיד מושלם נהניתי לכל אורך התהליך</p>
פורסם על ידי ‏‎<a href="#" role="button">Galit Bitton</a>‎‏ ב- <a href="https://www.facebook.com/galit.bitton.7/posts/10222133077450392">יום רביעי, 23 בספטמבר 2020</a></blockquote>
</div>
</div>
<div class="nature">
<div class="fb-post" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/liel.gov/posts/2724464070984846" data-show-text="true" data-width="20">
<blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/liel.gov/posts/2724464070984846" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
<p>רכשתי מאורי המקסימה צמיד מעלףףףףף הגיע עטוף בצורה מושלמת רואים את ההשקעה שלך בפרטים הקטנים </p>
פורסם על ידי ‏‎<a href="https://www.facebook.com/liel.gov">Liel Gov</a>‎‏ ב- <a href="https://www.facebook.com/liel.gov/posts/2724464070984846">יום שלישי, 21 באפריל 2020</a></blockquote>
</div>
</div>
<div class="nature">
<div class="fb-post" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=2065362006941957&amp;id=100004045347142" data-show-text="true" data-width="20">
<blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=2065362006941957&amp;id=100004045347142" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
<p>רכשתי מאורי 3 צמידים מושלמים, בדיוק במידה! מהממים, השירות מהיר, אורי מקסימה, שירותית אדיבה וסובלנית. הצמידים פשוט מושלמים!!!</p>
פורסם על ידי ‏<a href="#" role="button">טלי חיים</a>‏ ב- <a href="https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=2065362006941957&amp;id=100004045347142">יום שלישי, 14 באפריל 2020</a></blockquote>
</div>
</div>
<div class="nature">
<div class="fb-post" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/saritca/posts/10214276283455003" data-show-text="true" data-width="20">
<blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/saritca/posts/10214276283455003" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
<p>חייבת להחמיא ... זו לא פעם ראשונה שאני קונה אצל אורי, הפעם הזמנתי לעצמי כי הייתי חייבת משהו לנפש, הסבלנות של אורי...</p>
פורסם על ידי ‏‎<a href="#" role="button">Sarit Cohen Atia</a>‎‏ ב- <a href="https://www.facebook.com/saritca/posts/10214276283455003">יום שלישי, 24 במרץ 2020</a></blockquote>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script>// <![CDATA[
w3.slideshow(".nature", 9000);
// ]]></script>
```

When trying to fix it with other javascript codding I had the exact same problem:

```html
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script async="" defer="" crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/he_IL/sdk.js#xfbml=1&amp;version=v8.0" nonce=""></script>
<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides">
  
  <div class="fb-post" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/galit.bitton.7/posts/10222133077450392" data-show-text="true" data-width="20">
<blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/galit.bitton.7/posts/10222133077450392" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
<p>השרות האדיב, העיצוב המשגע, מעבר לזה שרכשתי צמיד מושלם נהניתי לכל אורך התהליך</p>
פורסם על ידי ‏‎<a href="#" role="button">Galit Bitton</a>‎‏ ב-&nbsp;<a href="https://www.facebook.com/galit.bitton.7/posts/10222133077450392">יום רביעי, 23 בספטמבר 2020</a>
</blockquote>
</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides">
  
  <div class="fb-post" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/meytal.grinberg/posts/10158027741254670" data-show-text="true" data-width="20"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/meytal.grinberg/posts/10158027741254670" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><p>אמאלה מושלם!!!!!
צמיד נעים,איכותי ומהמם.
מקבלת עליו מלא מחמאות...
שירות אישי ומשלוח סופר מהיר ושירותי!
ממליצה בחום❤❤❤
צמיד ראשון ובטוח לא אחרון</p>פורסם על ידי ‏‎<a href="#" role="button">Meytal Grinberg</a>‎‏ ב-&nbsp;<a href="https://www.facebook.com/meytal.grinberg/posts/10158027741254670">יום שישי, 7 בפברואר 2020</a></blockquote></div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides">
  
<div class="fb-post" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/tamila.meerzon/posts/3506844522677465" data-show-text="true" data-width="20"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/tamila.meerzon/posts/3506844522677465" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
<p>שלום לכולם.לפני כמה ימים מצאתי את האתר והזמנתי פעם הראשונה. 
עשיתי החלטה מצויינת. גם הכרתי מעצבת נחמדה ומקצועית וגם אישה...</p>פורסם על ידי ‏‎<a href="https://www.facebook.com/tamila.meerzon">Tamila Meerzon</a>‎‏ ב-&nbsp;<a href="https://www.facebook.com/tamila.meerzon/posts/3506844522677465">יום רביעי, 20 במאי 2020</a>
</blockquote></div>


</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot"></span> 
  <span class="dot"></span> 
  <span class="dot"></span> 
</div>

<script>
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 9000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
</script>


</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add CSS to fix this issue. Here is the CSS,

```
.fb_iframe_widget iframe, .fb_iframe_widget_fluid span{max-width: 100%;}
```